# Python iterating through a short spreadsheet and copying matching values into a large spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with pandas, trying to use a list of devices, device_master.xlsx, to automatically fill a number of columns in my main spreadsheet, detailed_billing.xlsx.

I can read the contents of both sheets, and I can make other transformations to my main spreadsheet, but I'm new to this and I can't figure out how to iterate through each line of device_master.xlsx sheet and compare it to/ populate the required columns in my main sheet.

So far what I'm doing to the rest of the sheet looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
#import re

# import the list of devices with work order numbers and project codes:

devmaster_xls = pd.read_excel('device_master.xlsx', 'device master', header = [0], index_col = None)
print('Device Master sheet columns:', devmaster_xls.columns, '\n') #debug, check the columns are right


# import the billing information which will need transforming with work order/ project codes:

data_xls = pd.read_excel('DetailedBilling.xlsx', 'Sheet1', header = [0], index_col = None)
print('Billing sheet columns read in:', data_xls.columns, '\n') #debug, check the columns before

data_xls.insert(13, 'WO Ref', '')
data_xls.insert(14, 'WO Description', '')
data_xls.insert(15, 'Project Code', '')

print('Billing sheet columns with WO additions:', 
data_xls.columns, '\n') #debug, check the columns after

wait = input("Press enter to continue...")


# magic sauce to add work order and cost tracking goes in here
# magic sauce to add work order and cost tracking goes in here
#




data_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('DetailedBilling_edit.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
data_xls.to_excel(data_writer, index = False)

#defining the book/sheet to work with
workbook = data_writer.book
worksheet = data_writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# formatting changes
worksheet.set_zoom(85)

server_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#800000', 'bold': True})
dollar_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': """_($* #,##0.00_);_($* -#,##0.00;_($* "0.00"_);_(@_)""", 'bold': True})
bold_fmt = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 34, server_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 85)
worksheet.set_column('F:F', 28)
worksheet.set_column('G:G', 9)
worksheet.set_column('H:K', 11, dollar_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('L:P', 12.5)
worksheet.set_column('O:O', 85)

#
#what size is this sheet? 
count_row = len(data_xls.index)
#count_row = data_xls.shape[0]
print("Total rows: ", count_row, '\n')

data_writer.save()
```

What I want to say is something like:

```
data_xls['WO Ref'].loc[(data_xls['Server'] = devmaster_xls['Device Name'])] = devmaster_xls['WO Ref']
```

I've tried putting it in a loop but haven't gotten very far with it - any assistance would be appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks to @frankyjuang I'm getting the right data, which is great, but for some reason I can't get it to write into the spreadsheet. I do this:

```
>>> for index, row in data_xls.iterrows(): 
... rowdata = devmaster_xls.loc[devmaster_xls['Device Name'] == row['Server']]
... print(index, rowdata['WO Ref'])
```

it looks good, returning something like:

```
555 19    REF###
Name: WO Ref, dtype: object
556 19    REF###
Name: WO Ref, dtype: object
557 19    REF###
Name: WO Ref, dtype: object
558 19    REF###
Name: WO Ref, dtype: object
559 19    REF###
Name: WO Ref, dtype: object
560 19    REF###
Name: WO Ref, dtype: object
561 19    REF###
Name: WO Ref, dtype: object
562 19    REF###
Name: WO Ref, dtype: object
563 19    REF###
Name: WO Ref, dtype: object
```

I'm trying to insert with this:

```
>>> for index, row in data_xls.iterrows(): 
... rowdata = devmaster_xls.loc[devmaster_xls['Device Name'] == row['Server']] 
... row['WO Ref'] = rowdata['WO Ref']
```

But `print(data_xls['WO Ref'])` shows the rows are NaN.

Comment: Could you put your updates in your post? It's really not readable in the comments :(

Comment: done, cheers @frankyjuang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my inexperience, I was struggling with the answer @frankyjuang provided - I couldn't fit my head around the results that I was getting versus what I wanted to achieve. So, after more research, I came up with the following solution, which has solved the problem:

First, we will need to index both spreadsheets with a shared key. In this case, it's the servernames, in the format `servername1.com`, `servername2.com`, etc. But - I don't want to permanently alter my dataframe, so instead, will create a new column which can be used as the index.

This copies the server column, converts it to lowercase to account for any case mismatches later, and sets it as the index:

```
data_xls['Serverindex'] = data_xls['Server'].str.lower() 
data_xls.set_index('Serverindex', inplace = True)
```

Grabbing my device master sheet:

```
devmaster_xls = pd.read_excel('device_master.xlsx', 'device master', header = [0], index_col = None)
```

And as above, creating the index from an existing column, converting it to lowercase on the way:

```
devmaster_xls['Devindex'] = devmaster_xls['Device Name'].str.lower() 
devmaster_xls.set_index('Devindex', inplace = True)
```

Then copying the relevant data from the device master sheet into the main sheet is as simple as:

```
data_xls.loc[:,'WO Ref'] = devmaster_xls.loc[:,'WO Ref'] 
data_xls.loc[:,'WO Description'] = devmaster_xls.loc[:,'WO Description'] 
data_xls.loc[:,'Project Code'] = devmaster_xls.loc[:,'Project code']
```

Finally, we don't want to write out that index, so:

```
data_xls = data_xls.reset_index(drop = True)
devmaster_xls = devmaster_xls.reset_index(drop = True)
```

If this method is really bad practice, I'd be interested to find out why, and what I could do to improve it. However it did solve the problem and is quick to implement!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the rows in `data_xls` by

```
for index, row in data_xls.iterrows():
    row['WO Ref']    # Get the data in this way
```

Find the corresponding row by

```
devmaster_xls.loc[devmaster_xls['Device Name'] == some_value]
```

Combine them

```
for index, row in data_xls.iterrows():
    the_row_you_want = devmaster_xls.loc[devmaster_xls['Device Name'] == row['WO Ref']]
    # do the operations you want
```

#### Note:

If you wish to do this many times, it is more efficient to make an index first, then use `.loc`

```
devmaster_xls = devmaster_xls.set_index(['Device Name'])
devmaster_xls.loc[row['WO Ref']]
```

#### Update:

Be careful that the `rowdata` is still a small dataframe with only one row. In order to obtain the value of it, you cannot do `rowdata['COLUMN']` directly. Instead, remove the single row by `iloc[0]`

```
row['WO Ref'] = rowdata.iloc[0]['WO Ref']
```

Or, append `iloc[0]` right after the `rowdata = ...`

```
rowdata = devmaster_xls.loc[devmaster_xls['Device Name'] == row['Server']].loc[0]
```

Comment: Thanks @frankyjuang - that is giving me the right data, which is great, but for some reason I can't get it to write into the spreadsheet. I do this:
`>>> for index, row in data_xls.iterrows():
...     rowdata = devmaster_xls.loc[devmaster_xls['Device Name'] == row['Server']]
...     print(index, rowdata['WO Ref'])`

it looks good. 

I'm trying to insert with this:
`>>> for index, row in data_xls.iterrows():
...     rowdata = devmaster_xls.loc[devmaster_xls['Device Name'] == row['Server']]
...     row['WO Ref'] = rowdata['WO Ref']`

But `print(data_xls['WO Ref'])` the rows are NaN..

Comment: That's not very readable, sorry, hope it's clear... Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes >:(

Comment: Answer updated. If you found it helpful, plz don't hesitate to pick me as the best answer.

Comment: That's giving me an error, unfortunately - 
`for index, row in data_xls.iterrows():` 

     `rowdata = devmaster_xls.loc[devmaster_xls['Device Name'] == row['Server']]`

     `row['WO Ref'] = rowdata.iloc[0]['WO Ref']`


and the error is
`IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`.

Comment: If no rows is matched, the error raised. Check if anything matched first.